# A problem about details in the proof of the theorem 6.5.3( principal eigenvalue for nonsymmetric elliptic operators) in Evans' PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

We consider in this section the boundary-value problem

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
L w &=\lambda w \quad \text { in } U \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\
w &=0 \quad \text { on } \partial U
\end{aligned}\right.$$
where $U$ is open and bounded,
$$L u=-\sum_{i, j=1}^{n} a^{i j} u_{x_{i} x_{j}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} b^{i} u_{x_{i}}+c u .$$

Let us for simplicity assume that  $a^{i j}, b^{i}, c \in C^{\infty}(\bar{U})$ , that  $U$  is open, bounded and connected, and that  $\partial U$  is smooth. We suppose also  $a^{i j}=a^{j i}(i, j=   1, \ldots, n)$  and

$$c \geq 0 \quad \text { in } U$$
THEOREM 3 (Principal eigenvalue for nonsymmetric elliptic operators).
(i) There exists a real eigenvalue  $\lambda_{1}$  for the operator  $L$ , taken with zero boundary conditions, such that if  $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$  is any other eigenvalue, we have

$$\operatorname{Re}(\lambda) \geq \lambda_{1}$$

(ii) There exists a corresponding eigenfunction  $w_{1}$ , which is positive within  $U$ .
(iii) The eigenvalue  $\lambda_{1}$  is simple; that is, if  $u$  is any solution of (1), then  $u$  is a multiple of  $w_{1}$ .

Proof . 1. Choose  $m=\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]+3$  and consider the Banach space  $X=   H^{m}(U) \cap H_{0}^{1}(U)$ . According to Sobolev Embedding Theorem, $X \subset C^{2}(\bar{U})$ . We define the linear, compact operator  $A: X \rightarrow X$  by setting  $A f=u$ , where  $u$  is the unique solution of

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
L u=f & \text { in } U \\
u=0 & \text { on } \partial U
\end{aligned}\right.$$

Next define the cone

$$C=\{u \in X \mid u \geq 0 \text { in } U\} .$$

According to the maximum principle,  $A: C \rightarrow C$

2. Hereafter fix any function  $w \in C$, $w \not \equiv 0$ . Employing the strong maximum principle and Hopf's Lemma, we deduce
   $$v>0  \ \ in \ \  U, \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}<0 \ \  on\ \   \partial U \ \ \ (2)$$
   for  $v=A(w)$ .
   Remember that  $w=0$  on  $\partial U$ . So in view of  (2)  there exists a constant  $\mu>0$  so that

$$\mu v \geq w \quad \text { in } U$$

My problem is: why such constant $\mu>0$ exists? I know we only need to consider the point near the boundary of $U$ and notice that $w=0$ on $\partial U$,we may need to apply Tailor's formula, and I believe the conclusion is true, but I just can't prove it clearly.
Can someone help me? I would be appreciated if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Since $v > 0$ (strictly positive) you can just define the function
$$
g = \frac{w}{v},
$$
and then take $\mu = \sup_U g$ so that $\mu \geq g$ a.e. in $U$ and therefore
$$
\mu \geq \frac{w}{v} \implies \mu v \geq w.
$$
Remark that since $w \in C$ and $v > 0$, it holds $g \geq 0$ and therefore $\mu \geq 0$. We can see that $g = 0$ a.e. only if $w=0$ a.e., but in this case since $v > 0$ we can take any $\mu > 0$ and $\mu v > w$ would hold.

Comment: But how do you show $\mu$ is not $+\infty$?@G.Gare

Comment: with my approach you should show that $v$ is not arbitrarily small, or if it is, that's the case for $w$ as well.